# What does a Thai Scented Candle impart?

Tags: cookies, smoking, thai-cuisine

[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P2RP3NA)

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

There is a traditional cookie that is pretty much just a thick sugar cookie that is baked and then put in a covered bowl with the candle overnight. I ran into it because I was looking at candy recipes, and some of the Thai candies called for sugar smoked like this.

Other than smoke, what flavors come from one if these? Are they ever used for savory applications?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried tasting the cookie pre-candle to see what kind of flavor it has prior?

Comment: @Phrancis, Nope, I just came across the recipe. There is nothing to it (just flour, oil, egg and sugar) until it is smoked. The candy I was looking at was just tamarind, rolled in this smoked sugar.

Answer (score 3):

I have learned from [SheSimmers](http://shesimmers.com/2011/04/how-to-perfume-food-with-thai-scented.html) that the primary ingredient and scent of these candles is [frankincense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankincense). It "imparts the scent of frankincense, [ylang ylang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cananga_odorata), [patchouli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patchouli), and [mace oil](http://www.botanical.com/botanical/mgmh/m/mace--01.html) to the food." I will expand upon this answer after my candle arrives from Amazon within a few days.